# Como pegar trechos específicos de um string em php

Tags: php

Estou usando um API adaptado que me retoma o seguinte dado em XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ajax>
    <cmd p="innerHTML" t="shurlmsg">
        <![CDATA[<div class="myWinLoadSD">This link is already on your list</div>]]>
    </cmd>
    <cmd p="js">
        <![CDATA[
           $('#shurlin').removeClass('ajaxloading');
           setTimeout("$('#shurlmsg').html('');", 4000);
           $('#noresult').remove();
           $('#urls').prepend('');
           $('#shurlin').val('');
           $('#shurlout').val('http://example.com/Um5-Cg').show().focus().select();
        ]]>
</cmd>
```

O que quero é pegar o URL encurtado `http://example.com/Um5-Cg`.

Comment: Você quer capturar a URL e encurtar ela em seguida? Ou você quis dizer "eu quero pegar essa url encurtada", se for isto então a resposta @xsquirrel parece ser um caminho.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar a URL usando expressões regulares.

```
$xml = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ajax>
    <cmd p="innerHTML" t="shurlmsg">
        <![CDATA[<div class="myWinLoadSD">This link is already on your list</div>]]>
    </cmd>
    <cmd p="js">
        <![CDATA[
           $('#shurlin').removeClass('ajaxloading');
           setTimeout("$('#shurlmsg').html('');", 4000);
           $('#noresult').remove();
           $('#urls').prepend('');
           $('#shurlin').val('');
           $('#shurlout').val('http://example.com/Um5-Cg').show().focus().select();
        ]]>
</cmd>
EOT;

preg_match("/\('#shurlout'\).val\('(https?:\/\/.*\/\S*)'\)/i", $xml, $resultado);

print_r($resultado);

echo $resultado[1];
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ('#shurlout').val('http://example.com/Um5-Cg')
    [1] => http://example.com/Um5-Cg
)
http://example.com/Um5-Cg
```